# in which absolute position of an object I clicked

Tags: javascript

In which absolute position of an object I clicked?

I tested with:

```
object.onclick=function(e){
     var touchX=e.touches[0].pageX;
     //touchX=e.touches[0].clientX;
     console.log(touchX);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for
http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2006/09/02/click-image-and-get-coordinates-with-javascript/